# 動的にテキストをセットした場合のplaceholderの表示について

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

jQueryのvalを使ってテキストボックスに動的にテキストをセットした場合にMacのsafariではplaceholderのテキストが非表示にならず、重なって表示されてしまいます。
フォーカス時にplaceholderを非表示にする方法は見つかったのですが、動的に値がセットされた場合にplaceholderを非表示にする方法はありますでしょうか？
勿論テキストがクリアされたらまたplaceholderを表示させなければいけないので、placeholderの値を空にすることはできません。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 手元にあるsafari10.1.2だとjqueryのvalによる値の代入をしてもplaceholderがきちんと消えます。再現性を取りたいので、再現できるHTML,Javacscriptのソースおよびsafariのバージョンを追記いただけますか？

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。何故か今はちゃんとplaceholderが非表示になるようになりました。また同様の現象が起きた場合に、どのような条件で発生するか検証してみます。